# Why are KDE apps running on unity too slow to load

Tags: unity, kile, okular, kate

I use a few KDE applications in ubuntu; Okular, Kate and Kile. And it seems to me that they take a lot longer to load than other programs like Evince and gedit.

1. Is it because I'm running unity instead of KDE or is that just the way it is?
2. What can be done to reduce the loading delay?

**Edit:**
After changing my hard drive to SSD the lag is gone (of course not only that, everything loads instantaneously now)

Comment: @UriHerrera I recommend posting that as an answer :)

Comment: @UriHerrera Would it be possible to launch the required KDE libraries on startup? (I edited the original question to include this)

Comment: Do you see the slowness each time you access a KDE app, assuming you do so more than once in a session?

Comment: @vasa1 No, once I open it for the first time, the next time opens up instantly.

Comment: Then should you really worry? @UriHerrera's explanation makes it clear that that is expected because the libraries need to load. I wouldn't bother doing anything in autostart just on this score.

Answer (score 5):

You could say that yes, Evince and Gedit use GTK libraries, these are already loaded by the rest of the environment. Launching the KDE software means launching more libraries which take more time because they're not already being used by other software.

I wouldn't add anything to autostart  as it will probably slow it down, once they're loaded  when you open one your KDE programs you're good to go.